# PHP - Form mail converting line breaks to spaces

Tags: php, html, forms, line-breaks

I have a `<textarea>` in a form for user comments, and when the contents are passed to form mail, the line breaks are being converted to spaces. How can I preserve the line breaks that the form's user types in?

relevant php:

```
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
// This grabs the comments from the submitted form

//...

$to = $configEmail;

$subject = "Website Order Received: $offer";

$contents = "blah blah blah...";
if (!empty ($comments)) {
    $contents = $contents."\nComments: $comments\n\n";
}

//...

mail($to, $subject, $contents);
```

And in the HTML end of the form... (the comments are put into the form if it's submitted with errors, so data isn't lost)

```
<label>Comments / Questions</label>
<textarea name="comments"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
```

If I type:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

It remains like that if the form is submitted with errors, so `$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];` is definitely preserving the line breaks. But the **plain-text** e-mail gives me:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

How can I preserve the line breaks?

Comment: How does it look if you use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. Might be just your e-mail client that is picky.

Comment: Any place I have `/n` it works fine. My guess is that the string in `$comments` doesn't have `/n` for its line breaks the way the rest of the e-mail contents do.

Comment: Are you sending the mail in plain text or html? I understood the first, but the answers so far suggest the second..Anyway, it's \n, not /n

Comment: It's plain text, *not* HTML. And you're right, it's `\n`.

Comment: I faced this problem once. Do one thing, before send, replace all `\n`s with `\n\r`. I don't know is it the correct answer or not but a try would be worth of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line breaks coming from the textarea are `\n` not `<br>`..
So replace the `\n` by `<br>` before sending the mail..

```
$body= str_replace("[enter]", "\n",$body);
```

Rember user double quoutes in "\n"...

Comment: Actually, I think it's the other way around...though you may well have answered my question

Comment: Try this...actually I too had the same problem last yr..so remember from that time..

Comment: I tried `$comments = str_replace("[enter]", '\n', $comments);` (where "[enter]" is actually a line break), and I got `line 1\nline2\nline3` - so that didn't quite work.

Comment: Dude convert them to <br> not \n

Comment: It's a **plain text** email, not HTML.

Comment: I changed `'\n'` to `"\n"` and it now works. `$comments = str_replace("[enter]", "\n", $comments);` So...use double quotes, not single quotes

Comment: Theres a better function to do this, built into php. The other answer covers it, and this still requires html

Comment: @Ascherer - As Damien said, nl2br() would require the e-mail be in html format. It is not. It is in plain text format.

Comment: @mouseas i know, thus the "and this still requires html"

Answer (score 1):

Try the nl2br() function, if it doesn't initially work try to send the message as an HTML email.

Comment: nl2nr() changes newlines to html <br>, so he _needs_ html mail to give them a reason to be there..