# Textarea output doesn't leave lines

Tags: php, html, css

I have a textarea in which the user enters his data. I want to make the PHP code leave lines at places where the user has. Suppose the user enters -

```
My name is Harry. 
I live in LA.
```

The out put will be

```
My name is Harry.I live in LA.
```

Please tell me the function/command we use to solve this problem(I think its a PHP problem)

Thanks in advance.

HTML Code -

```
<textarea rows='1' cols='50' id='p-text' class='p-textarea' placeholder = 'Write something about yourself here..'> </textarea>
```

I will output this in a  tag, not a textarea.

@zrvan-

Output on var_dump($_GET['t'); is

```
string(31) "My name is Harry. I live in LA."
```

Comment: how are you passing the data to PHP ? can you include your HTML ?

Comment: You are probably outputting the text on a HTML page. Use `nl2br()` to create HTML line breaks

Comment: @ManseUK Im using AJAX to pass the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture newline from a textarea input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844465/capture-newline-from-a-textarea-input)

Comment: Do you display the output in a browser? Because the textarea will have newlines and the browser will not display those as newlines unless you either wrap the output text in `<pre />` or run something like `nl2br()` in PHP.

Comment: Yesterday I answered similar question refer that..if still some problem lemme noe..:) [Yesterdays Ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717701/php-form-mail-converting-line-breaks-to-spaces/8717759)

Comment: @zrvan Im outputting this in a <div> tag. I cannot use a <pre> tag

Comment: @user1025469: This seems to be a more or less common issue, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183466/new-line-problem-when-doing-ajax-post-with-jquery for a solution (using a regular expression before sending the data and convert newline to `<br />`)

Answer (score 8):

nl2br() should solve that if you're echo-ing the string. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Make sure you don't strip the newlines when you add content to the database though.

Comment: nl2br() is not working for me. Please suggest me something else

Comment: @user1025469 show your PHP ... what do you mean its "not working"

Comment: My php is simple.
<?php
$t = nl2br($_GET['t']);
echo $t;
?>

Comment: 1. Do you strip the newlines when adding the string to the database?
2. Do you strip the newlines before you echo them?

Comment: @user1025469: could you post the result of `var_dump ($_GET['t']);` (as an edit to your question), when you've sent in the contents of a textarea with line breaks?

Comment: Im not putting this into the db yet due to this problem. No i dont strip the newlines. The code i commented is all thats in the code.

Comment: This is not the solution for this specific problem. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183466/new-line-problem-when-doing-ajax-post-with-jquery for more information.

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728717/textarea-output-doesnt-leave-lines/8728745#8728745

Answer (score 3):

In fact the output is something like this

```
My name is Harry.\nI live in LA.
```

just use http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php for that :)

/edit:
mat was faster :) flag his answer as solution :)

Comment: By a split second.. ;) That's  the only thing i don't like about StackOverflow. I am sometimes typing  half an hour on an answer to find out that someone posted the exact same a minute before me. Ah well, that's offtopic.